# Delete script form xml document in SQL Server

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2014

I want to delete content from xml or txt document in SQL Server 2014 for this example:

```
<div class="infotagtitle">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var sc_project=9934926; 
    var sc_invisible=1; 
    var sc_security="00dd8003"; 
    var scJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ?
    "https://secure." : "http://www.");
    document.write("<sc"+"ript type='text/javascript' src='" +
    scJsHost+
    "statcounter.com/counter/counter.js'></"+"script>");
    </script>
</div>
```

Output:

```
<div class="infotagtitle">
</div>
```

Comment: How is this stored in table a `XML` datatype or what ?

Comment: .txt file or xml file . output in table.

Comment: Check here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190254.aspx

Comment: possible to create for this example?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'text'. for this line: type='text/javascript'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text code from the question is clearly HTML and not well-formed XML.
As such, the text can't be simply casted or converted to the XML type.
Which means XML type functions like f.e. `SET @myXML.modify('delete //script');` aren't an option.

This example code uses a table variable to demonstrate updating a table with an NVARCHAR that contains HTML with script tags.
It uses PATINDEX to find the script code in the HTML.

An update is looped till no records remain with a script tag in the html.

```sql
declare @T table (Id int identity(1,1), html_text nvarchar(max));
insert into @T (html_text) values
(N'<html>
<body>
  <div class="infotagtitle">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var sc_project=9934926; 
    var sc_invisible=1; 
    var sc_security="00dd8003";
    var scJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ?
    "https://secure." : "http://www.");
    document.write("<sc"+"ript type=''text/javascript'' src=''" +
    scJsHost+
    "statcounter.com/counter/counter.js''></"+"script>");
    </script>
  </div>
  <div class="othertagtitle">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.write("<script type=''text/javascript'' src=''" +
    otherHost+
    "othercounter.com/counter/counter.js''></"+"script>");
    </script>
  </div>
</body>
<html>');

declare @N INT, @Counter INT = 0;
select @N = count(*) from @T where patindex('%<script %',html_text) > 0;

while (@N > 0 AND @Counter < 10)
begin
 set @Counter = @Counter + 1; -- just a safety measure to avoid an infinite loop

 update @T 
 set html_text = concat(substring(html_text,1,patindex('%<script %',html_text)-1),substring(html_text,patindex('%</script>%',html_text)+9,len(html_text)))
 where patindex('%<script %',html_text) > 0;

 select @N = count(*) from @T where patindex('%<script %',html_text) > 0;
end;

select * from @T;
```

Comment: This can be achieved without a loop using `Substring` and `Patindex` or `Charindex`

Comment: @Prdp It can? How to do that for multiple script tags? I'm always happy to learn.

Comment: thanks @Prdp , good, how to do that for multiple script? very thanks